# Creating a counter based on user input

Tags: python-2.7

```
from CaseManager import d2
import shutil

d11 = d2 + '/ReconstructedObjects/'
if not os.path.isdir(d2):
    try:
        os.mkdir(d2)
    except OSError as esc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

nFiles = ('How many objects would you like to concatenate?')
catFile1 = raw_input('Specify the first Object ID')
catFile2 = raw_input('Specify the second Object ID')
catFile3 = raw_input('Specify the third Object ID')

d11 = open(CatFile, 'wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(open(catFile1, 'rb'), d11)
shutil.copyfileobj(open(catFile2, 'rb'), d11)
shutil.copyfileobj(open(catFile3, 'rb'), d11)
d11.close()
```

Hi there, what I would like to do, is concatenate any number of files together which the user specifies. The user will be asked to specify the number of files from the nFiles var.

The limitations of this code is that, if the user specifies that they want to concatenate four files, they are unable to do so.

How would I dynamically implement the `shutil.copyfileobj(open(catFile3, 'rb'), d11)` specifically based on the user unput in nFiles?

Comment: Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use loops and maybe lists. The simplest way to transform your code to work with any number of files, is first to loop `nFiles` times, each time asking for another file name and putting it in a list. Then loop over the list of filenames, doing the copying operation on each one.

But, you could also compact things even more and do the concatenating step immediately after being told the file name, without needing to keep it in a list:

```
n_files = int(raw_input('How many objects would you like to concatenate?')
with open(d11, 'wb') as destination_file:
    for i in range(n_files):
        fn = raw_input('Specify the ID of Object #{}'.format(i+1))
        with open(fn, 'rb') as cat_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(cat_file, destination_file)
```

I've changed up some variable names to follow common Python style (`lowercase_with_underscores` for most variables). You can of course use your own style if you prefer (just be consistent!). I've also used `with` statements to handle closing the files automatically for us, which is better than relying upon them getting closed when they have no more references.